# Test multiple criteria against separate lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large spreadsheet containing multiple sets of information. I have provided a shortened example of the spreadsheet below. Please note that every table in the real list contains considerably more terms.

I need to test whether the terms in column A fall within the list in column E **and** whether the terms in column B fall within the list in column G.

For example, looking at row 2, does the 'Type 1' data (A) fall within the list in column E (A,C,D) **and** does the 'Type 2' data (X) fall within the list in column G (X,Y). In this instance the answer is yes and therefore 'TRUE' would be entered in column C.

I have tried to use the formula below but am not getting very far with it.

Any suggestions?

```
=IF((A2=$E$2:$E$4)*(B2=$G$2:$G$3),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be sufficient no matter how large your actual lists become.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, E$2:E$4, 0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2, F$2:F$3, 0)))
```

Those E$2:E$4 and F$2:F$3 ranges could be full column if desired; e.g. E:E and F:F.

[image: TRUE_FALSE]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I used the formula with an     IF function so that I could change the terms "TRUE" and "FALSE".

Comment: There will be no issue using this with 3 or more criteria will there?

Comment: None to speak of. [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is a very efficient function and [ISNUMBER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) has little to no impact on calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jeeped's answer above, I used this formula. This is because I want to use different terms to "TRUE" or "FALSE".

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$4,0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$3,0))),"TRUE","FALSE")
```